# kwargs reserved word in python. What does it mean?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am using Python trying to figure out a key word and I see the word, "`kwargs`", which I know is some kind of argument in the called function but I can not find what it means or stands for anywhere.

For example, this entry in the Python documents says...

```
read_holding_registers(address, count=1, **kwargs)
```

#### Parameters:

```
address – The starting address to read from
count – The number of registers to read
unit – The slave unit this request is targeting
```

It looks like a reference to a pointer to pointer but that is all I
can tell...

This does NOT even use "`**kwargs`"  in the parameters list   It uses
what looks to me like, "`unit`" instead of "`kwargs`".

I can NOT seem to find anywhere what `kwargs` means.

Maybe it is "Key Word arguments" ?  What am I missing here ?

Any ideas on help here ?
thank you !
boB

Answer (score 14):

`**kwargs` means keyword arguments. Its actually not a python keyword, its just a convention, that people follow. That will get all the key-value parameters passed to the function. For example,

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print args, kwargs
func(1, "Welcome", name="thefourtheye", year=2013)
```

will print

```
(1, 'Welcome') {'name': 'thefourtheye', 'year': 2013}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought it might be a general purpose args placeholder but was not sure.  Why the double asterisks ?  It makes me think it is an indexed operation of some sort...  Pointer to a pointer.   I am still unsure here.

Comment: @user3024070 Its by the syntax of the language. There are no pointers in Python. Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters It has complete explanation of this

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it means "keyword arguments", but `kwargs` is not actually a reserved word. It is just the idiomatic thing to call the argument that collects all the unused keyword arguments.